# Grouby filter, count each category, duration and identify second last based on date

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below.

```
   ID   Status  Date        Cost
0   1   F       2017-06-22  500
1   1   M       2017-07-22  100
2   1   P       2017-10-22  100
3   1   F       2018-06-22  600
4   1   M       2018-08-22  150
5   1   P       2018-10-22  120
6   1   F       2019-03-22  750
7   2   M       2017-06-29  200
8   2   F       2017-09-29  600
9   2   F       2018-01-29  500
10  2   M       2018-03-29  100
11  2   P       2018-08-29  100
12  2   M       2018-10-29  100
13  2   F       2018-12-29  500
14  3   M       2017-03-20  300
15  3   F       2018-06-20  700
16  3   P       2018-08-20  100
17  3   M       2018-10-20  250
18  3   F       2018-11-20  100
19  3   P       2018-12-20  100
20  3   F       2019-03-20  600
21  3   M       2019-05-20  200
22  4   M       2017-08-10  800
23  4   F       2018-06-10  100
24  4   P       2018-08-10  120
25  4   F       2018-10-10  500
26  4   M       2019-01-10  200
27  4   F       2019-06-10  600
```

where

F=Failure,

M=Maintenance

P = Planned

Step1 - Ignore the rows if the last raw per ID is not F, expected out put after this as shown below.

```
ID  Status  Date        Cost
0   1   F   2017-06-22  500
1   1   M   2017-07-22  100
2   1   P   2017-10-22  100
3   1   F   2018-06-22  600
4   1   M   2018-08-22  150
5   1   P   2018-10-22  120
6   1   F   2019-03-22  750
7   2   M   2017-06-29  200
8   2   F   2017-09-29  600
9   2   F   2018-01-29  500
10  2   M   2018-03-29  100
11  2   P   2018-08-29  100
12  2   M   2018-10-29  100
13  2   F   2018-12-29  500
14  3   M   2017-03-20  300
15  3   F   2018-06-20  700
16  3   P   2018-08-20  100
17  3   M   2018-10-20  250
18  3   F   2018-11-20  100
19  3   P   2018-12-20  100
20  3   F   2019-03-20  600
22  4   M   2017-08-10  800
23  4   F   2018-06-10  100
24  4   P   2018-08-10  120
25  4   F   2018-10-10  500
26  4   M   2019-01-10  200
27  4   F   2019-06-10  600
```

Now, for each id last status is failure

Then from the above df I would like to prepare below Data frame

```
ID  No_of_F  No_of_M  No_of_P  SLS  NoDays_to_SLS NoDays_SLS_to_LS
1   3        2        2        P    487           151
2   3        3        2        M    487           61
3   3        2        2        P    640           90
4   3        1        1        M    518           151
```

SLS = Second Last Status

LS = Last Status

I tried following code to calculate the duration.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Date', 'Status'])
df['D'] = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff().dt.days


ID  Status  Date    Cost    D
0   1   F   2017-06-22  500 nan
1   1   M   2017-07-22  100 30.00
2   1   P   2017-10-22  100 92.00
3   1   F   2018-06-22  600 243.00
4   1   M   2018-08-22  150 61.00
5   1   P   2018-10-22  120 61.00
6   1   F   2019-03-22  750 151.00
7   2   M   2017-06-29  200 nan
8   2   F   2017-09-29  600 92.00
9   2   F   2018-01-29  500 122.00
10  2   M   2018-03-29  100 59.00
11  2   P   2018-08-29  100 153.00
12  2   M   2018-10-29  100 61.00
13  2   F   2018-12-29  500 61.00
14  3   M   2017-03-20  300 nan
15  3   F   2018-06-20  700 457.00
16  3   P   2018-08-20  100 61.00
17  3   M   2018-10-20  250 61.00
18  3   F   2018-11-20  100 31.00
19  3   P   2018-12-20  100 30.00
20  3   F   2019-03-20  600 90.00
21  3   M   2019-05-20  200 61.00
22  4   M   2017-08-10  800 nan
23  4   F   2018-06-10  100 304.00
24  4   P   2018-08-10  120 61.00
25  4   F   2018-10-10  500 61.00
26  4   M   2019-01-10  200 92.00
27  4   F   2019-06-10  600 151.00
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "Step1 - Ignore the rows if the last raw per ID is not F, expected out put after this as shown below.". Btw. it seems the table you listed below this sentence is exactly your input table, was that by design, or is it maybe a copy-paste issue? Is it, that you want to count all of the F, M, P per group, but for the date calculation you want to use the last non-F-element?

Comment: @jottbe Step1 is just to explain how I get the expected out put

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach. It doesn't require the last row to be a 'F', so no .iloc[-2] is required:

```
# the following two lines are only required if the date column is a string
# and the dataframe is not already sorted
df['Date']= df['Date'].astype('datetime64')
df.sort_values(['ID', 'Date'], axis='index', ascending=True, inplace=True)

# add some auxillary columns
df['aux_date']= df['Date'].where(df['Status'] != 'F', pd.NaT)
df= pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['Status'])], axis='columns')

# calculate the relevant dates and the sums of the statuses
grouped= df.groupby('ID')
aggregated= grouped.agg({'Date': 'min', 'aux_date': 'max', 'No_of_F': 'sum', 'No_of_M': 'sum', 'No_of_P': 'sum'})
aggregated['max_date']= grouped['Date'].apply(max)

# calculate the date differences
aggregated.loc[~aggregated['aux_date'].isnull(), 'NoDays_to_SLS']=    aggregated['aux_date'] - aggregated['Date']
aggregated.loc[~aggregated['aux_date'].isnull(), 'NoDays_SLS_to_LS']= aggregated['max_date'] - aggregated['aux_date']

# drop the columns that were just inserted for calculation
aggregated.drop(['Date', 'aux_date', 'max_date'], axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

The output is:

```
    No_of_F  No_of_M  No_of_P NoDays_to_SLS NoDays_SLS_to_LS
ID                                                          
1         3        2        2      487 days         151 days
2         3        3        1      487 days          61 days
3         3        2        2      640 days          90 days
4         3        2        1      518 days         151 days
5         2        2        2      487 days           0 days
```

Note: I inserted ID 5 to show what I mean by that I don't rely on the last record to be an F. ID 5 is just a copy of the rows of ID 1 with the last F-line remove. That's why `NoDays_SLS_to_LS` is zero for that line.

The `NoDays...`-columns are of type timedelta64. If you rather want to store them as ints, you can do:

```
aggregated['NoDays_to_SLS']=    aggregated['NoDays_to_SLS'].dt.days
aggregated['NoDays_SLS_to_LS']= aggregated['NoDays_SLS_to_LS'].dt.days
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and [`transform.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) to create a mask to filter your `DataFrame`:

```
s = df.Status.eq('F').groupby(df.ID).cumsum().groupby(df.ID).transform('idxmax')
mask = s.index <= s
df_filtered = df[mask]
```

Then you can use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to create your additional columns:

```
df_new = pd.crosstab(df_filtered.ID, df_filtered.Status).add_prefix('No_of_')
df_new['SLS'] = df_filtered.groupby('ID')['Status'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-2])
df_new['NoDays_to_SLS'] = (df_filtered.groupby('ID')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-2]) - df_filtered.groupby('ID')['Date'].first()).dt.days
df_new['NoDays_SLS_to_LS'] = (df_filtered.groupby('ID')['Date'].last() - df_filtered.groupby('ID')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-2])).dt.days
```

[out]

```
Status  No_of_F  No_of_M  No_of_P SLS  NoDays_to_SLS  NoDays_SLS_to_LS
ID                                                                    
1             3        2        2   P            487               151
2             3        3        1   M            487                61
3             3        2        2   P            640                90
4             3        2        1   M            518               151
```

Comment: out put is having two No_of_M columns. The second No_of_M column is wrong. That is not required.

Comment: Only way this could happen is with leading/trailing white space or different casing for “M”... check thst there is no white space? Eg “ M” or “M “ (notice the spaces)